# Chaining Tasks and Debugging

Tags: c#

In a part of my app I need to perform series of state updates that are long running complex operations. I have designed my code in a way that states are immutable, such that passing an old state to a state constructor will provide a new state based on that old state. In one part of my app, a new state creation is launched on each keypress, but the state created from the last keypress must be piped into the next key press's state creation.

I'm attempting to wrap the state creation into a chain of tasks by reassigning the currently running task to a continuation of the running task. Below is the pseudo-code and test to determine if I understand tasks correctly. Instead of a state object I'm just using a string and some delay. Will the below code accomplish my task?

The second problem is I cannot unit test this as it completes immediately. Can you help me understand how to refactor this to become a passing test?

```
Task<string> GettingString {get;set;}

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestChaining()
{

    GettingString = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Task.Delay(3000);
        return "Foo";
    });

    var s = await GettingString;

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) 
    { 
        if(GettingString.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
        {
            GettingString = GettingString.ContinueWith((s) => 
            {
                Task.Delay(1000);
                return s+ "Bar";
            });
        }
    }

    // I think it takes 6 seconds to get here. If not, what am I misunderstanding?
    Assert.IsTrue(s == "FooBarBarBar");
}
```

Edit to add: just want to clarify that reassigning `GettingString` is important as this property is the "source of truth" as to the eventual final state after chaining all of the intermediate state constructions.

Comment: You are `await`-ing the `GettingString` before entering the loop. So inside the loop it's guaranteed that `GettingString.Status` is `Completed`, so the loop does nothing but increment the `i`. By the way, it is not recommended to mix `await` with the `ContinueWith`, it is recommended to use `await` everywhere.

Comment: What do you expect an un-`await`ed call to `Task.Delay` will do?

Answer (score 2):

You are `await`-ing the `GettingString` before entering the loop. So inside the loop it's guaranteed that `GettingString.Status` is `Completed`, so the loop does nothing but increment the `i`. Moreover, you are not `await`-int the `Task.Delay()`, so there are no delays at all.

And finally, it is not recommended to mix `await` with the `ContinueWith`, it is recommended to use `await` everywhere.

The solution may looks like the following

```
        GettingString = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            return "Foo";
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var locS = await GettingString;
            GettingString = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    return locS + "Bar";
                });
        }

        var s = await GettingString;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(s == "FooBarBarBar");
```

Here we `await`-int the results on the each loop iteration then starting the new task based on the current task result.

Please note that I store the current value in the `locS` variable on each loop iteration to capture this value in the `Task.Run`.

And if we wrap this in the `async` function, then the called will get the `Task<string>` as return value, which will give `FooBarBarBar` when finished. You can even more simplify the task-related logic and finally get something like this

```
    async Task<string> Test()
    {
        var str = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            return "Foo";
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            str = await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return str + "Bar";
            });
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(str == "FooBarBarBar");
        return str;
    }
```

Here we removed the task chaining at all and replaced it with await-ing the intermediate results and adding them into the final result.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just have a "fallback" on running tasks, such that after a delay you can handle a "build up" of other Tasks that need awaiting, and avoid getting choked by a very long running task that prevents all the new ones from starting, you can do the following:

```
var taskPool = new List<Task>();

while (taskPool.Any()) {
    if (PendingTasks.Any()) {
        taskPool.AddRange(PendingTasks);
        PendingTasks.Clear();
    }
    taskPool.Add(Task.Delay(500));
    _ = await Task.WhenAny(taskPool);
    
    taskPool = taskPool.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
}
```

Something roughly like that, you'd need to refine it to handle exceptions and whatnot of course, but the principle is you can have a running "pool" of pending tasks, and then you can wrap them in a `Task.WhenAny`, and to prevent the problem of "what if they never finish" you add in a short `Task.Delay` so you know at least that task will finish in a short time, and then you clear all the completed tasks out of the pool.